# Mover controle do formulário com Thread

Tags: .net, vb.net, thread

Eu estou tentando fazer um joguinho 2D, nele quando o personagem se movimenta as paredes se movimentam também de uma forma que pareça algum tipo de jogo, no entanto usar timers seria uma má ideia pois quando eu adicionar muitas paredes (PictureBox) ficaria muito lento o formulário, então a outra opção seria criar uma Thread para separar o trabalho, o código que eu uso para mover as paredes estão aí.

```
    Private Scene As New Thread(AddressOf MoveWalls)

    Private Sub MoveWalls()
        For Each Wall As PictureBox In Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)()
            If Not Wall.Tag = "Player" Then
                Wall.Location = New Point(Wall.Location.X + X2, Wall.Location.Y + Y2)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Scene.Start()
    End Sub
```

**OBS:** O jogador também é uma PictureBox então para Thread não usar como parede alterei a Tag do Jogador para Player

Quando eu executo a aplicação nada acontece, mas eu acrescentei uma label para testar se ele conseguia alterar o valor e ao fazer isso apareceu um erro na tela.
[image: Erro]

Eu até tentei a dica de solução que ele recomenda mas não obtive sucesso. [Link para solução recomendada](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)
Alguém sabe me dizer se é possível alterar a localização das paredes usando Thread? Se sim preciso de ajuda, se não alguma ideia melhor?

Comment: Por que você não teve sucesso seguindo o link que postou? Ele da exemplos claros do que você deve fazer.

Comment: Tenho um pouco de experiência no Vb.net, mas em todo esse tempo só mexi duas vezes com  thread (contando com essa), eu fiz até o meu código seguindo essa dica de solução mas não obtive resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve utilizar o método `Invoke` para que seu atualização da GUI ocorra na `thread` principal.

Exemplo:

```
Public Sub InternalMoveWall(ByVal wall As Control, ByVal x As Int64, ByVal y As Int64)
    If wall.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(Sub() InternalMoveWall(wall, x, y))

    Else
        wall.Location = New Point(wall.Location.X + x, wall.Location.Y + y)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub MoveWalls()
    For Each Wall As PictureBox In Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)()
        If Not Wall.Tag = "Player" Then
            InternalMoveWall(Wall, 100, 100)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```